# Page not scrolling in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I have tried as hard as I could but I can't figure out why [this page](http://library.iated.org/publications/INTED2011) hasn't any chance of scrolling (mouse, keys, scrollbars missing) in Chrome. In other major browsers everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 62 in ui.checkbox.css, change

```
.ui-checkbox input, .ui-radio input {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    left: -99999999px;
    top: -99999999px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px none;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

to

```
.ui-checkbox input, .ui-radio input {
    visibility: visible;
    left: -9999px;
    top: -9999px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px none;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should be try with:
Create new id next `<body>`

```
<div id="container">
      <div class="bloque_superior">...</div>
      <div class="contenido">...</div>
      ...
</div>
```

css

```
body {
   font-family: Tahoma,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: black;
   background-color: white;
   background-image: url(img/bg.png);
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#container {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 970px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have implemented your suggestion but it's still the same, no scrolling.

Comment: Your container must be stay out of content.